# Linking a bookmark and ToC entry to top of landscape page

Tags: hyperref, rotating, bookmarks, lscape

I have an unnumbered (starred) chapter in landscape orientation. The `\label{...}` places an anchor/jump target at the beginning of the line (`\phantomsection`). Clicking at the connected bookmark leads to this position at the end of the page (red anchor in the image). If the pdf document is displayed in continuous (double) row mode, the user just sees the end of the page. I would like to place the anchor at the top of the page/end of the line (green anchor in the image), or changing the bookmark's destination (and the destination of the link in the table of contents) from "dest: Destination name." to "page: the page where the label is on", which I could do "in-text" with `\usepackage{refcount}` and `\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{link text}`. How can I accomplish this (or solve the link-issue in another way)?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[extension=pdf,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,%
  hyperindex=true,setpagesize=false,pdfpagelayout=SingleColumn]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\clearpage%
\setkeys{Grot}{units=360}%
\begin{landscape}%
\phantomsection%
\chapter*{A Long List\label{LongList}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A Long List}

Some text.

\verb|\begin{longtable}...|
...
\verb|\end{longtable}|

\end{landscape}%
\setkeys{Grot}{units=-360}%

Normal text.

\end{document}
```

[image: How to move the anchor position?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[extension=pdf,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,%
  hyperindex=true,setpagesize=false,pdfpagelayout=SingleColumn]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\setkeys{Grot}{units=360}%
\begin{landscape}%
\phantomsection%
\chapter*{A Long List}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{A Long List}{\Roman{page}}{page.\Roman{page}}}%
\bookmark[level=chapter,page=\arabic{page}]{A Long List}%

Some text.

\verb|\begin{longtable}...|
...
\verb|\end{longtable}|

\end{landscape}%
\setkeys{Grot}{units=-360}%

Normal text.

\end{document}
```